# Recommended FS to share Windows, OS X host and Linux

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, filesystems, osx-leopard, arch-linux

I have a 120GB SD hard drive that I have put into an Oker portable USB enclosure it comes with two USB output presumably one is redundant just to get extra power.

I regularly use 3 host computers:

- Home (Archlinux)
- Work (Windows 7)
- Laptop (Mac OS X 10.6)

I would like to install VirtualBox 4 on each and use the same Archlinux guest VM across all three hosts via the SSD USB drive.

Initially I though easy, format USB drive as FAT and throw the relevant VM disk file on it. But FAT32 has a 2GB (or 4GB?) file limit.

Which filesystem should I use which will be recognized by all three hosts? I appreciate that I may have to use a plugin or two, which will give me the least headaches?

Comment: 4GB is the file limit of FAT32 ( http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938937.aspx )

Comment: His virtual disk file will be larger than 4GB.

Answer (score 3):

ExFAT should be accessible out of the box on all three operating systems with full read/write capabilities and none of FAT32's file size limits.

NTFS is limited to read only on Mac OS X (and I believe archlinux) without the use of NTFS-3G/FUSE software/packages.

Comment: Exfat is supported in Snow Leopard, but beta in linux http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExFAT#Support_on_Other_Platforms

Answer (score 1):

The ntfs3g driver works very well in Linux, so while it might not be a purist solution, I would still pick NTFS over FAT variants, if I had the choise. FAT variants are just inferior to NTFS/HPFS/ETX3.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](http://macntfs-3g.blogspot.com/) to read/write to NTFS on the mac, and the same software can work in archlinux (see [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NTFS-3G)).